# MVC Return view from another method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am unable to end response in case of some condition

eg below (in Upload Action Method), if Logerror method invoked i just want to return view(browser) without further action. i.e return from Upload Action Method.
        Plase find modified question what i am trying to achive,
In case of error i want to return view by stopping all further opeartion

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
       return View();
    }


    public ActionResult Upload()
    {

       int i=1;
       DoSomethingFirst();  
       //if LogError i dont want execute code below, rather it should end responce
       //should not reach here  

       string s="This should not be executed in case of LogError()";

       return View("Index");

    }

    public void DoSomethingFirst()
    {

       try{
           DoSomethingSecond();
       }
       catch(exception ex)
       {
           LogError();
       }

    }

    public void DoSomethingSecond()
    {

       try{
           DoSomethingThird();
       }
       catch(exception ex)
       {
           LogError();
       }

    }


    public void DoSomethingThird()
    {

       try{
           DoSomethingother();

       }
       catch(exception ex)
       {
           LogError();
       }

    }   


    private LogError()
    {
        Viewbag.Error="Error details";
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't return a result from the current method:

```
DoSomething();
```

But *this* does:

```
return DoSomething();
```

If you want to end execution of the current method, you need to do something which exits the method.  Basically, either return from the method or throw an exception.  Since `DoSomething` returns a result, presumably you want to return *that* result.  So simply add a `return` statement when invoking the method.

> i tried wit RedirectToAction("Index");

Same issue.  You'd need to *return* the result:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

---

**Edit:** Based on your edit to the question, the overall concept still remains.  Focusing on this part of your code here:

```
var s = DoSomethingFirst();  
//if true i dont want execute code below, rather it should end responce
//should not reach here
```

In order to exit the method, *any method* in C#, you need to either `return` or `throw`.  So the first question is... Which do you want to do here?  If you want to return a redirect, for example, then return a redirect:

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeAction");
```

If you want to return the default view, return that:

```
return View();
```

If you want to throw an exception:

```
throw SomeException("Some Message");
```

The choice is yours.  You just need to define:

1. What you want this method to return or throw under this condition.
2. How will you know the condition.

For that second point, your code comment says:

```
//if true ...
```

Does this mean `DoSomethingFirst()` returns a `bool` indicating success or failure?  Then that would be a simple `if` statement:

```
if (!DoSomethingFirst())
    return View();
```

---

**Another Edit:** Based on your comment below:

> Inside LogError mehod called by any child method in action method, i want to update view with error message and end the operation without further operation

How will your `Update` method *know* that something it invoked internally called `LogError()`?  What information does `DoSomethingFirst()` return to indicate this fact?  Currently it doesn't.  Your various `DoSomething` methods are all *swallowing exceptions*, which means they are internally handling exceptions so that consuming code *doesn't* know about them.

If you want consuming code to know about an exception, re-throw that exception.  For example:

```
public void DoSomethingFirst()
{
    try
    {
        DoSomethingSecond();
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
        LogError();
        throw; // <-- this will re-throw ex without modifying it
    }
}
```

This returns information from `DoSomethingFirst()`, specifically the fact that an error occurred.  Your consuming code can then check for that error:

```
try
{
    DoSomethingFirst();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // You should *probably* do something with ex too.  So far all of your "logging" has been ignoring the actual error.
    return View();
}
```

Regardless of the structure you build, the basics don't change.  In order for consuming code to know something about the code it invokes, that invoked code has to expose that information.  In order to end execution of a method, you have to either `return` or `throw`.  Don't hide exceptions from consuming code if you want consuming code to *respond* to those exceptions.

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Index") i tried it doesnt work inside DoSomething

Comment: @user3815413: Define "it doesn't work".  Show what you tried in the question and explain the observed behavior vs. the expected behavior.

Comment: @user3815413 you still need to `return DoSomething();`

Comment: i  am not sure where the DoSomething is called, need not to be directly in action method, it may be 5th child method inside method in action method.i wrote eg to simplify the question

Comment: @user3815413: `"i am not sure where the DoSomething is called"` - Can you look at the code and find out?  Because the original problem still remains.  If you want to return the result, you need to use the `return` keyword.

Comment: @user3815413 you need to post code that *still reproduces the problem* otherwise it is literally impossible to help you.

Comment: If `DoSomething` is 5 levels down, you still need to return the result all the way up. The question of why you're returning a redirect result from 5 levels deep in the call stack is another issue.

Comment: Plase find modified question what i am trying to achive, Snippet updated,
In case of error i want to return view by stopping all further operation,
Basically i want to display Validation error in screen by breaking opeartion

Comment: @user3815413: First of all, that code doesn't compile because `DoSomethingFirst()` doesn't return anything, but you're trying to set its return value to a variable.  Aside from that, the overall point still remains.  In order to "stop" the method, you need to either return or throw an exception.  Which do you want to do in this case?  And, after calling `DoSomethingFirst()`, how will your code *know* that it needs to "stop" the rest of the method?  You say "if true" in the comment in your code, but what is "true"?

Comment: @David : It is Modified, it is not true, objective is if LogError method called, i tshould return to view without continuing further

Comment: @user3815413: I've updated the answer.  The bottom line is still the same, no matter how you structure your methods.  In order to end the execution of the current method, either `return` something or `throw` something.  It's up to you which you want to do.  For example, if you want to "return the view", that would be: `return View();`

Comment: @David: Thanks a lot you for your response, //if true ...was initially wrote for the intention that Logerror method will be called.
My issue is simple..

Inside LogError mehod called by any child method in action method, i want to update view with error message and end the operation without further operation
\n
even if i wrote return RedirectToAction("Index") inside Logerror method
My expection is control is transferred to Index Action and since nothing is there in Index method excepet return view, view will be refershed with error message

Comment: @user3815413: I've updated the answer again.  Regardless of how you structure this, the basic premise of the answer doesn't change.  In order to end execution of a method, you either `return` or `throw`.

Comment: @David : Thanks for all your response, now i can throw after each logerror call so that it will reach till root action method in the root action method catch block return view

Comment: This is a classic XY Problem - if you are trying to implement generic error handling, you should be rethrowing exceptions and handling them in some kind of filter.